# Graph analytics: choosing best location

Tags: graph-theory

Lets say I have the latitude and longitude coordinates of various people. I also have the latitude and longitude of 2 specific locations.

I got a function that calculates the distances between the people coordinates and the locations. How can I pick which location has the 'lowest cost'?

Summing the distances doesn't seem to be the most appropriate way of choosing the location. Maybe taking the square of the distances in order to give more cost to people being really far?

Thinking of the problem as a Graph and considering the nodes to be `people` and specific `locations`, and as edges the `people -> location` witch have weights the distances between the person and the location.Is there a function that could give the 'best' location? An example:
[image]

Here the red nodes represent the locations and the green one the people. Which red node is better to be chosen thinking of distance?

Comment: This question has no answer unless you explicitly define what the distance between two points is. If it's the number of edges, then both red points are equidistant from all other green points.

Comment: the distances between the edges are the physical distances (ex 10km)

Comment: Is your graph embedded in the cartesian plane? In other words, does the *length* of an edge matter, or is each edge the same length? If it's the latter, then there's no distinction between the red points.

Comment: The edges have different length.